# Understanding reflection calculation in Wave Digital Filters

Tags: dsp

I'm trying to grasp this implementation. It involves calculating the reflected wave (b1) using the reflection coefficient and the incident plus reflected waves at two ports in a series adaptor.

The code snippet from wdf serial adaptor is as follows:

```
const auto b1 = port1.wdf.b - port1Reflect * (x + port1.wdf.b + port2.wdf.b);
```

I understand that port1Reflect is the reflection coefficient already computed based on the port resistances

But what equation does this calculation of the reflection of b come from? I've been searching for papers and I don't see anything.

https://github.com/Chowdhury-DSP/chowds ... adaptors.h (https://github.com/Chowdhury-DSP/chowdsp_wdf/blob/main/include/chowdsp_wdf/wdft/wdft_adaptors.h)

I have been checking this paper [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jingjiez/portfolio/gtr-amp-sim/pdfs/Wave%20Digital%20Filters%20Theory%20and%20Practice.pdf](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejingjiez/portfolio/gtr-amp-sim/pdfs/Wave%20Digital%20Filters%20Theory%20and%20Practice.pdf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.